# Add input ng-model search to group filtering

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-ng-model

I'd like to add input ng-model search to my angular application

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Main">
<input ng-model="dddd"><br>
<div ng-repeat="playerPerTeam in playersToFilter() | filter:filterTeams">
<b>{{playerPerTeam.team}}</b>
  <li ng-repeat="player in players | filter:{team: playerPerTeam.team}">{{player.name}}</li> 
  </div>
</div>
```

whole code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/lukasz9999/070ebre7/2/

The input ng-model should filter player.name

thank you for any tips!!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one example:

https://jsfiddle.net/rokoala/143ea6xL/

searchFilter as ng-model of input and filter on ng-repeat.

```
<input ng-model="searchFilter"><br>

<li ng-repeat="player in players | filter:{team: playerPerTeam.team} | filter:searchFilter">{{player.name}}</li>
```

Comment: GREAT! THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: @luke9999 You should mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem, so that it helps fellow developers with similar queries.